# SELECT DISTINCT on two columns, with multiple columns returned

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am using the below query

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP,substr(DBNAME,1,10) as DBNAME, MSGSEVERITY as SEV, MSGNUM, substr(MSG,1,80) as MSG_trunc FROM TABLE ( PD_GET_LOG_MSGS( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30 DAYS)) AS T WHERE MSGSEVERITY NOT IN 'I'  ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
```

Below is the output

```
TIMESTAMP                  DBNAME     SEV MSGNUM      MSG_TRUNC
-------------------------- ---------- --- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------
2019-11-17-05.45.33.266795 ABC        W          1602 ADM1602W  Rollforward recovery has been initiated.

2019-11-17-05.45.39.086945 XYZ        W          1602 ADM1602W  Rollforward recovery has been initiated.

2019-11-17-05.45.42.960668 ABC        W          1602 ADM1602W  Rollforward recovery has been initiated.

2019-11-17-05.45.48.287948 XYZ        W          1602 ADM1602W  Rollforward recovery has been initiated.

2019-11-17-07.04.09.038759 ABC        W          1611 ADM1611W  The rollforward recovery phase has been completed.

2019-11-17-07.04.14.688757 XYZ        W          1611 ADM1611W  The rollforward recovery phase has been completed.

2019-11-17-07.04.18.339282 XYZ        W          1611 ADM1611W  The rollforward recovery phase has been completed.
```

Can I get the output with distinct DBNAME and MSGNUM

The output should be as below

```
TIMESTAMP                  DBNAME     SEV MSGNUM      MSG_TRUNC
-------------------------- ---------- --- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------
2019-11-17-05.45.33.266795 ABC        W          1602 ADM1602W  Rollforward recovery has been initiated.

2019-11-17-05.45.39.086945 XYZ        W          1602 ADM1602W  Rollforward recovery has been initiated.

2019-11-17-07.04.09.038759 ABC        W          1611 ADM1611W  The rollforward recovery phase has been completed.

2019-11-17-07.04.14.688757 XYZ        W          1611 ADM1611W  The rollforward recovery phase has been completed.
```

Comment: Did I get it right, that you need to get 1 row from each group (DBNAME,  MSGNUM) with the earliest timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP
, substr(DBNAME, 1, 10) as DBNAME
, MSGSEVERITY as SEV
, MSGNUM
, substr(MSG, 1, 80) as MSG_trunc 
, ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DBNAME, MSGNUM ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) RN
FROM TABLE (PD_GET_LOG_MSGS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30 DAYS)) AS T 
WHERE MSGSEVERITY NOT IN 'I'
)
WHERE RN=1
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `max` timestamp and use `group by`.

```
SELECT max(TIMESTAMP)
    , DBNAME
    , SEV
    , MSGNUM
    , MSG_trunc 
FROM    
    (SELECT TIMESTAMP
        , substr(DBNAME,1,10) as DBNAME
        , MSGSEVERITY as SEV
        , MSGNUM
        , substr(MSG,1,80) as MSG_trunc 
    FROM TABLE (PD_GET_LOG_MSGS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30 DAYS)) AS T 
    WHERE MSGSEVERITY NOT IN 'I') t  
GROUP BY DBNAME
    , SEV
    , MSGNUM
    , MSG_trunc 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: I got the below error :
 
SQL0119N  An expression starting with "DBNAME" specified in a SELECT clause,
HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or
it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column
function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.  SQLSTATE=42803

Comment: @AbhiramVarma, yup, forgot to include the dbname, try again

Comment: I have added the dbname in group by clause then I got the below error:

SQL0134N  Improper use of a string column, host variable, constant, or
function "Group by column 1".  SQLSTATE=42907

Comment: have you added ` substr(DBNAME,1,10)` in the group by?

Comment: I have executed the above query and got the error 

SQL0134N  Improper use of a string column, host variable, constant, or
function "Group by column 1".  SQLSTATE=42907

Comment: @AbhiramVarma, try again updated query, i used subquery now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204109/discussion-between-abhiram-varma-and-).

Comment: Now i got this error : SQL0134N Improper use of a string column, host variable, constant, or
function "MSG_TRUNC". SQLSTATE=42907

Comment: MSG column is a CLOB datatype.I think this is the reason for the above error